# How to Have a Pure HTML Sub Directory In WP Site

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have a website powered by WordPress which is working perfectly. Now I need to have a Custom Directory called `app` and a very simple HTML markup called `app.php` or `app.html` inside there nevertheless that it is a WP website (at least for after `/app/` directry.

Can yo please let me know if this is doable in WordPress and how I can do it? Right now it is going to `page.php` page from the themese!

Thanks

Comment: Where have you placed your `app` directory? Are the `app` directory contents tied to WordPress or independent of WP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by either of the two ways:

#### Way #1

Create a WordPress page template first in your WordPress theme (or child theme). Suppose the name of the file is: `my-app.php`, and the content is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: My App Page
 */

echo "Here's what I want to show";
```

Now, create a WordPress page from Pages. Make the page slug to `app`.
[image: slug 'app']

Select the "My App Page" template from the right meta box's "Templates".
[image: Page Template]

Save the page, and you can access the page using `example.com/app/`. What you want to show in that page, place all of them in the Page Template file.

The page template method is helpful regardless whether your your page content is tied with WordPress or not.

[More details on Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) - Developer Resources

#### Way #2

Create your `app/` folder in WordPress root, where folders like `wp-admin`, `wp-content`, and `wp-includes` resides.

Make your `index.html` or `index.php` file there, with respective contents.

Access the folder using `example.com/app/`. You are done! :)
[image: /app directly]

But I cannot assure whether the folder stays or not after WordPress updates. I never tried.

Comment: This folder won't be removed after WordPress update.